# Angular2 created new app folder in my .js folder

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular2. I'm using the heros guide as a sort of template. In tsconfig.json, I changed the `outDir` to `app/js` to send all my js files there. Forgot about it and came back this morning to see there had been another app folder created in the js folder, so something like app\js\app, and all the new files that I had been working on are in there. This is creating an issue with the npm start. npm start can't detect a bs-config.json? How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem with the setup in one of your config files, most likely `tsconfig.json` itself, such that another part of the code is set to create the `app` folder, after the initial `app/js` folder has already been created. To be certain of this I'd need you to post the contents of all the main angular2 config files (or maybe just `tsconfig.json` for starters), but that's where I would suggest you start searching, anyway.